# How use react accessible accordion?

Tags: reactjs

I created small react application. I created react accessible accordion all collapse opened while page loading opened fine. if click any accordion automatically closed all accordion. I need if click any accordion that particular hide and show otherwise accordion opened.

could you please check my code

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemHeading,
    AccordionItemButton,
    AccordionItemPanel,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';

 

   

     import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
        
        export default function Apdemo() {
            return (
              <Accordion preExpanded={['a', 'b', 'c']} >
                    <AccordionItem uuid="a">
                        <AccordionItemHeading>
                            <AccordionItemButton>
                                What harsh truths do you prefer to ignore?
                            </AccordionItemButton>
                        </AccordionItemHeading>
                        <AccordionItemPanel>
                            <p>
                                Exercitation in fugiat est ut ad ea cupidatat ut in
                                cupidatat occaecat ut occaecat consequat est minim minim
                                esse tempor laborum consequat esse adipisicing eu
                                reprehenderit enim.
                            </p>
                        </AccordionItemPanel>
                    </AccordionItem>
                    <AccordionItem uuid="b">
                        <AccordionItemHeading>
                            <AccordionItemButton>
                                Is free will real or just an illusion?
                            </AccordionItemButton>
                        </AccordionItemHeading>
                        <AccordionItemPanel>
                            <p>
                                In ad velit in ex nostrud dolore cupidatat consectetur
                                ea in ut nostrud velit in irure cillum tempor laboris
                                sed adipisicing eu esse duis nulla non.
                            </p>
                        </AccordionItemPanel>
                    </AccordionItem>
                    <AccordionItem uuid="c">
                        <AccordionItemHeading>
                            <AccordionItemButton>
                                Is free will real or just an illusion?
                            </AccordionItemButton>
                        </AccordionItemHeading>
                        <AccordionItemPanel>
                            <p>
                                In ad velit in ex nostrud dolore cupidatat consectetur
                                ea in ut nostrud velit in irure cillum tempor laboris
                                sed adipisicing eu esse duis nulla non.
                            </p>
                        </AccordionItemPanel>
                    </AccordionItem>
                </Accordion>
            );
        }
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hi David I update clear information could you please check my question and please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> if click any accordion automatically closed all accordion. I need if click any accordion that particular hide and show otherwise accordion opened.

If you check [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-accessible-accordion) for the component you're using, the very first option is:

> **allowMultipleExpanded : `boolean` [*optional*, default: `false`]**
> Don't autocollapse items when expanding other items.

If you want to allow multiple expanded elements and not auto-collapse other elements when expanding one, set that option to `true`:

```
<Accordion allowMultipleExpanded preExpanded={['a', 'b', 'c']}>
```

Comment: thanks david i used  allowMultipleExpanded ={true} working fine.